# What does Approximation Property mean?

Tags: real-analysis

I am following *Mathematical Analysis* by *Tom Apostol*. I have a confusion here.

> Examples:
>   3. The half-open interval $S = [0,1)$ is bounded above by 1 but has no maximum element. It's minimum element is 0.
>
> For these sets like in Example 3, which are bounded above but have no maximum element, there is a concept which takes place of the maximum element. It is called *least upper bound* or *supremum* as is defined as follows

And there is a property called Approximation property

> *Theorem (Approximation property)*: Let $S$ be a set of nonempty set of Real numbers with a supremum, say $b = \sup S$. Then for every $a < b$ there is some $x$ in $S$ such that $$a < x \leq b$$

My question is shouldn't it be like this $ a \leq x < b$ since the set $S$ does not contain b? Or does it imply that we approximate $b$ to be in $S$?

Also if the the maximum element of the set exist, then would it be the *supremum*?

And finally, there is a statement

> ... The completeness axiom allows us to introduce irrational numbers in real number system, and it gives the real number system a property of continuity that is fundamental to many theorems in analysis.

How does completeness axiom allows us to introduce irrational number in real number system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The supremum $\sup A$ is the least upper bound, which exists for every set $A$that is nonempty and bounded from above (and usually the definition is extended so that $\sup A=+\infty$ if $A$ is not bounded from above and $\sup A=-\infty$ if $A=\emptyset$).
*If* the set $A$ does have a maximal element, then this element is at the same time an upper bound and is obviously the least such bound, hence $\max A=\sup A$ if $\max A$ exists.
For the same reason, you cannot say that *definitely* the least upper bound $\sup A$ is *not* an element of $A$.
In that sense the text is misleading when it says that the supremum is a concept that is introduced *only* for sets that don't have a maximum. It's not a replacement, rather an extension.

The completeness is the "only" property that makes $\mathbb R$ differ from $\mathbb Q$. In $\mathbb Q$, the set $\{x\in\mathbb Q\mid x^2<2\}$ is nonempty and bounded from above (e.g. by $42$), but there is no *least* upper bound in $\mathbb Q$. On the other hand, completeness of $\mathbb R$ gives us he existence of a number $w:=\sup\{x\in\mathbb Q\mid x^2<2\}$ that is a least upper bound. One can easily show that $w^2=2$ (because neither $w^2<2$ nor $w^2>2$ are possible). Since there is no rational solution of $X^2-2=0$, we conclude that $w$ is irrational.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you should quote Apostol correctly: the statement about the existence of irrational numbers does not come *finally*, but rather at the beginning of section 1.10. This makes a difference, since the sentence may be interpreted as a *pour parler*. And indeed it is: Apostol assumes that $\mathbb{R}$ exists, so that the set of irrational numbers is just $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$. In my opinion, Apostol was thinking of very particular irrational numbers, like $\sqrt{2}$. You can define $\sqrt{2}$ as a supremum of a set of rational numbers (see for instance Rudin's *Principles of mathematical analysis*), and you need the axiom of completeness.

You did not write correctly the approximation property, but, to answer your question, Apostol's statement is true. The supremum *may* belong to $S$, so that a strict inequality would be wrong. And you are right when you write that sup=max when the sup belongs to your set.

Answer (score 0):

Supremum might be inside or outside the set. Think about the set of even numbers less than or equal to 100. Supremum is 100. Now if you take a = 99 then you need the less than or equals part in your original question.